# Why is y~x1+x1:x2 and y~x1+x2+x1:x2 interpreted as equivalent models?

Tags: r, regression, anova, interaction, lm

I came across unsuspected behavior of the lm function in R (3.6.1.) when evaluating model with interaction. Here is a toy example:

```
#generate data
set.seed(0)
data = data.frame(x1 = factor(rep(0:1, 10)),x2 = rbinom(20,10,1/2),y = rnorm(20))

#model and its submodel without main effect of x2
m1 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data=data)
m2 = lm(y ~ x1 + x1:x2, data=data)

#compare models -> it's the same model
anova(m2, m1)
```

I would expect m1 and m2 to differ by 1 degree of freedom. However, the term x1:x2 in m2 is interpreted the different way then in m1 and it generates two regressors instead of one.

I understand the interpretation of each coefficients in m1 and m2. The thing that bothers me is what logic is hidden under this behavior and how I can perform submodel test when I need to omit one main effect and preserve its interaction with a nominal factor.

Comment: it's been too long to give a good answer but I'm pretty sure that the reasoning has to do with the the idea that including an interaction without its main effect doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Inspect both `m1` and `m2` and you'll understand :)

Comment: @Firebug Thanks, I already did that. The problem is not that I don't understand the models. The question is why is " : " interpreted different way in each model and how can I avoid this behavior.

Comment: `:` is not interpreted in a different way, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in fact the same model.

Long story short, if we inspect both models

> ```
> m1
>
> #Call:
> #lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data = data)
> #
> #Coefficients:
> #(Intercept)          x11           x2       x11:x2  
> #    0.26253     -0.10427     -0.05206     -0.02664  
>
> m2
>
> #Call:
> #lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x1:x2, data = data)
> #
> #Coefficients:
> #(Intercept)          x11       x10:x2       x11:x2  
> #    0.26253     -0.10427     -0.05206     -0.07870
> ```

Since you specified the interaction `x1:x2` in both models, and since `x1` is a factor, in `m2` R understands that you specified `x2` slopes for both levels of `x1`, as we can see in the model summary in the terms `x10:x2` and `x11:x2`.

This makes sense, it does not report anymore the "baseline" `x2` effect but instead one effect per level in `x1`, which amounts to the same model as `m1`.

---

The link between both models' coefficients is simply shown to be:

```
coef(m1)[4]
#     x11:x2 
#-0.02663733 
diff(coef(m2)[3:4])
#     x11:x2 
#-0.02663733
```

Comment: Do you know a way to avoid this behavior? In some cases it is desired to exclude one main effect without replacing it with a second interaction term.

Comment: @DanielDostal if `x1` is not a factor it works, but you'll have to carefully think about the model formulation that way. The coding in `x1` will have an impact on the model specification, and I personally don't think it makes sense anyways to specify the model like that.

Comment: Thanks, @Firebug . Changing the factor to quantitative variable works in this example but it has its caveats when the factor has many levels. I know that the interpretation of the model is strange but it some context it makes sense.

Comment: @DanielDostal - you could also go the painful way of expanding `x1` into a collection of dummy variables, calculating all the cross-variables with `x2`, putting them into the regression, and leaving out the `x1` dummies.